# NDK Error occured while importing telegram source code from github

Tags: android, c++, api, android-ndk, telegram

I downloaded telegram open source code for android from the following the link   https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram. While importing the project am getting the following errors:

```
  External Native Build Issues
  Build command failed.
  Error while executing process C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk 
  -bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk 
 NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a 
 NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-14 
 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/armv7/release/obj 
 NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\armv7\release\lib 
NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
Android NDK: ERROR:C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk:WebRtcAec: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file    
Android NDK: Check that C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/jni/./libtgvoip/external/libWebRtcAec_android_armeabi-v7a.a exists  or that its path is correct   
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
Error:executing external native build for ndkBuild 
C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk
Build command failed.
Error while executing process C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null 
APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk 
NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86 NDK_DEBUG=1 
APP_PLATFORM=android-23 
NDK_OUT=C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/x86_SDK23/debug/obj 
NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\x86_SDK23\debug\lib 
NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14 
 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
Android NDK: ERROR:C:\Users\user\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk:WebRtcAec: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file
```

How do I fix these?

Comment: So, have you done what the error message asks you to do: _"Check that C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/Telegram-master/TMessagesProj/jni/./libtgvoip/external/libWebRtcAec_android_armeabi-v7a.a exists  or that its path is correct"_

Comment: i haven't understand what that error is ?

Comment: there are no files/folder inside jni/libtgvoip folder

Answer (score 9):

The reason for your error is that the libtgvoip is a submodule and you did not clone the repository recursively so the required library has not been checked out.

To fix this go to the folder where you cloned the project and run

```
 git submodule update --init --recursive
```

This will check out the required submodule

Comment: if you don't mind can you explain step by step procedure to do that ?

Comment: There is nothing else to do than to run that command in the directory you put the sourcecode

Comment: i do this . but problem not fixed and my jni/libtgvoip is Epmty!!

Answer (score 4):

no contents inside `jni/libtgvoip`

so either do  `git submodule update --init --recursive` or

download from [here](https://github.com/grishka/libtgvoip.git) and past it inside
`jni/libtgvoip`