# Android ndk error on prebuilt-library.mk file

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, telegram

I want to compile telegram source but Android Studio shows the following error

`Android NDK: Aborting. Stop`

Clicking on this error opens `prebuilt-library.mk` file pointing to the following line

```
 = $(call __ndk_info,Check that $(prebuilt path) exists, or that its path   is correct)
```

I have updated NDK & LLDB & Cmake and tested again. This time I got the following error

```
External Native Build Issues
        Build command failed.
         Error while executing process C:\Users\Abolfazl\AppData\Local\Android  \Sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null      APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=F:\tearch-ui-android-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk   NDK_APPLICATION_MK=F:\tearch-ui-android-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-14 NDK_OUT=F:/tearch-ui-android-master/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/armv7/release/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=F:\tearch-ui-android-master\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\armv7\release\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-14 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}
      Android NDK: ERROR:F:\tearch-ui-android-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk:WebRtcAec: LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file    
     Android NDK: Check that F:/tearch-ui-android-master/TMessagesProj/jni/./libtgvoip/external/libWebRtcAec_android_armeabi-v7a.a exists  or that its path is correct   
     process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.
Build command failed.
```

and

```
 Error:(44, 0) *** Android NDK: Aborting    .  Stop.
 <a href="openFile:C:\Users\Abolfazl\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\ndk-bundle \build\core\prebuilt-library.mk">Open File</a>
```

Content of `anderoid.mk` is

```
   # Copyright (C) 2010 The Android Open Source Project
   #
   # Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
   # you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
    # You may obtain a copy of the License at
    #
   #      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
   #
 # Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    # distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  # WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 # See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
   # limitations under the License.
   #

   # this file is included from prebuilt-shared-library.mk or
   # prebuilt-static-library.mk to declare prebuilt library binaries.
    #

   $(call assert-defined, LOCAL_BUILD_SCRIPT LOCAL_MAKEFILE   LOCAL_PREBUILT_PREFIX LOCAL_PREBUILT_SUFFIX)

  $(call check-defined-LOCAL_MODULE,$(LOCAL_BUILD_SCRIPT))
     $(call check-LOCAL_MODULE,$(LOCAL_MAKEFILE))
    $(call check-LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME)

  # Check that LOCAL_SRC_FILES contains only the path to one library
     ifneq ($(words $(LOCAL_SRC_FILES)),1)
    $(call __ndk_info,ERROR:$(LOCAL_MAKEFILE):$(LOCAL_MODULE): The  LOCAL_SRC_FILES for a prebuilt library should only contain one item))
      $(call __ndk_error,Aborting)
       endif

       bad_prebuilts := $(filter-out      %$(LOCAL_PREBUILT_SUFFIX),$(LOCAL_SRC_FILES))
       ifdef bad_prebuilts
     $(call __ndk_info,ERROR:$(LOCAL_MAKEFILE):$(LOCAL_MODULE):    LOCAL_SRC_FILES should point to a file ending with "$(LOCAL_PREBUILT_SUFFIX)")
     $(call __ndk_info,The following file is unsupported: $(bad_prebuilts))
       $(call __ndk_error,Aborting)
       endif

        prebuilt_path := $(call local-prebuilt-path,$(LOCAL_SRC_FILES))
       prebuilt := $(strip $(wildcard $(prebuilt_path)))

      ifndef prebuilt
     $(call __ndk_info,ERROR:$(LOCAL_MAKEFILE):$(LOCAL_MODULE):   LOCAL_SRC_FILES points to a missing file)
      $(call __ndk_info,Check that $(prebuilt_path) exists, or that its path is correct)
   $(call __ndk_error,Aborting)
    endif

     # If LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME is defined, it will be used to name the file
     # in the TARGET_OUT directory, and then the installation one. Note that
    # it shouldn't have an .a or .so extension nor contain directory       separators.
    #
   # If the variable is not defined, we determine its value from    LOCAL_SRC_FILES
    #
   LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := $(strip $(LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME))
   ifndef LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME
   LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := $(notdir $(LOCAL_SRC_FILES))
  LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME :=   $(LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME:%$(LOCAL_PREBUILT_SUFFIX)=%)
  endif
   $(eval $(call ev-check-module-filename))

  # If LOCAL_BUILT_MODULE is not defined, then ensure that the prebuilt is
    # copied to TARGET_OUT during the build.
  LOCAL_BUILT_MODULE := $(strip $(LOCAL_BUILT_MODULE))
   ifndef LOCAL_BUILT_MODULE
  LOCAL_BUILT_MODULE :=     $(TARGET_OUT)/$(LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME)$(LOCAL_PREBUILT_SUFFIX)
       LOCAL_OBJECTS      := $(prebuilt)

     $(LOCAL_BUILT_MODULE): $(LOCAL_OBJECTS)
    endif

     LOCAL_OBJS_DIR  := $(TARGET_OBJS)/$(LOCAL_MODULE)
     LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=

      include $(BUILD_SYSTEM)/build-module.mk
```

Please help me!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NDK Error occured while importing telegram source code from github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43435037/ndk-error-occured-while-importing-telegram-source-code-from-github)

Comment: i have download libtgvoip library and show error now.

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':TMessagesProj'.
> executing external native build for ndkBuild F:\tearch-ui-android-master\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk